# Why is this minimal polynomial not the correct minimal polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, solution-verification

Given $\sin\left(\frac \pi {18}\right)$ I thought finding the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ would be trivial. Using that $\sin(3x)= 3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$ I just let $x=\frac{\pi}{18}$ which gave me $\frac 1 2 = 3t-4t^3$ given a substitution of $t=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{18}\right)$. This isn't right. What did I oversee?

As a side note, this is my attempt at showing the angle is not trisectable.

Comment: WolframAlpha shows $8x^3-6x+1$, which is equivalent to your answer. Why do you say yours is wrong?

Comment: @player3236 Forgive me, it's been a long week. You're absolutely right.